# If a property of my model object is an array of a custom object, how do I let users append objects to it?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm making an app where the user can create groups, and fill these groups with people. Groups are showed in a list and link to GroupViews, where there is a list of people part of that particular group.

The list of and creation of groups work as expected; the user can create groups and clicking any group takes the user to that specific groups own view.

The list of and creation of people don't work; when the user attempts to append a person to the people list it falls between the AddPersonView and GroupView and does not show up in the list.

Below is my current attempt at a solution:

Models.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Group: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var people: [Person]

    init(name: String) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.people = [Person]()
    }
}

struct Person: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}
```

ModelView.swift

```
import Foundation

class GroupList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var groups = [Group]()
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var groupList: GroupList

    @State private var showingAddGroupView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(groupList.groups) { group in
                NavigationLink(destination: GroupView(group: group.people)) {
                    Text(group.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingAddGroupView.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Add group")
                })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddGroupView) {
            AddGroupView(groupList: self.groupList)
        }
    }
}
```

AddGroupView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddGroupView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var groupList: GroupList

    @State private var name = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Name", text: self.$name)

            Button(action: {
                self.groupList.groups.append(Group(name: self.name))
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                    Text("OK")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GroupView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct GroupView: View {
    var group: [Person]

    @State private var showingAddPersonView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(group) { person in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(person.firstName)) {
                        Text("\(person.firstName) \(person.lastName)")
                    }
                }

                .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddPersonView) {
                    AddPersonView(group: self.group)
                }
            }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                self.showingAddPersonView.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Add person")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

AddPersonView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddPersonView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var group: [Person]

    @State private var firstName = ""
    @State private var lastName = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("First name", text: self.$firstName)

            TextField("Last name", text: self.$lastName)


            Button(action: {
                self.group.append(Person(id: UUID(), firstName: self.firstName, lastName: self.lastName))
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                    Text("OK")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "When the user attempts to append a person to the people list it falls between the AddPersonView and GroupView" -- what exactly happens? Do you get an error of some sort? If so, what is it>

Comment: No errors, there just isn't anything added to the list in GroupView. I tried putting a for loop in the dismiss button of AddPersonView that prints every item of the array and that will print what the user just added. However if I close the AddPersonView and open it anew the array will be empty again and only print the newest addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out:

the problem is exactly there what Lou said - structs will be copied. you must change and work on your observable object - not on copies.

```
import SwiftUI

import Foundation

struct Group: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var people: [Person]

    init(name: String) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.people = [Person]()
    }
}

struct Person: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}

class GroupList: ObservableObject {

    @Published var groups = [Group]()

    func getGroupBy(id: UUID) -> Group? {

        let result = groups.filter { $0.id == id }

        if result.count == 1 {
            return result[0]
        }
        return nil
    }
    func getGroupIndex(id: UUID) -> Int? {

        return groups.firstIndex { $0.id == id }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var groupList: GroupList

    @State private var showingAddGroupView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(self.groupList.groups) { group in
                NavigationLink(destination: GroupView(group: group).environmentObject(self.groupList)) {
                    Text(group.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingAddGroupView.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Add group")
            })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddGroupView) {
            AddGroupView().environmentObject(self.groupList)
        }
    }
}

struct AddGroupView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var groupList: GroupList

    @State private var name = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Name", text: self.$name)

            Button(action: {
                self.groupList.groups.append(Group(name: self.name))
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                    Text("OK")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GroupView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var groupList: GroupList

    var group: Group

    @State private var showingAddPersonView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(self.group.people) { person in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(person.firstName)) {
                        Text("\(person.firstName) \(person.lastName)")
                    }
                }

                .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddPersonView) {
                    AddPersonView(group: self.group).environmentObject(self.groupList)
                }
            }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                self.showingAddPersonView.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Add person")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct AddPersonView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    @EnvironmentObject var groupList : GroupList
    @State var group: Group

    @State private var firstName = ""
    @State private var lastName = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("First name", text: self.$firstName)

            TextField("Last name", text: self.$lastName)


            Button(action: {
                if let index = self.groupList.getGroupIndex(id: self.group.id) {
                    self.groupList.groups[index].people.append(Person(id: UUID(), firstName: self.firstName, lastName: self.lastName))
                    self.group = self.groupList.groups[index]
                }
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                    Text("OK")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(GroupList())
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! I'm so relieved, thank you! Man I've been scratching my head for the better part of a week and you just swept in here and fixed it like that. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in GroupView, with this line

```
 var group: [Person]
```

When you call AddPersonView, you are sending a copy of the array and the view appends a person to that copy and then it is lost when the view dismisses.

You must pass something that is shared. Probably this should all be in an `ObservableObject` and not local view variables.

Pass down the GroupList object or bindings to its internals

Comment: I think that's where I had my problem. I have an ObservableObject class for the Group array which is why I guess that works? But if I create a new ObservableObject class for the Person array it's no longer connected to a specific group?

Also I'm not sure what you mean by "Pass down the GroupList object or bindings to its internals". I'm sorry, I'm very new to this!